# Check Httpconnection is open or not in blackberry

Tags: networking, blackberry

Before making `HttpConnection` from blackberry application i want to check if  it is open or not?. Because without checking that when i tried to make a connection i got `class net.rim.device.api.io.ConnectionClosedException`.

EDIT: Posted the code from the OP's answer.

Below is my code for the http connection.

```java
public String makePostRequest(String[] paramName, String[] paramValue) {
    StringBuffer postData = new StringBuffer();
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(this.url);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
                postData.append(paramName[i]);
                postData.append("=");
                postData.append(paramValue[i]);
                postData.append("&");
        }
        String encodedData = postData.toString();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", (new Integer(
                encodedData.length())).toString());

            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Constants.COOKIE_TOKEN);


        byte[] postDataByte = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
         out = connection.openOutputStream();
        out.write(postDataByte);

        DebugScreen.Log("Output stream..."+out);
        DebugScreen.Log("Output stream..."+connection.getResponseCode());
        // get the response from the input stream..
        inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
        DebugScreen.Log("Input stream..."+inputStream);
        byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream);
        response = new String(data);

    } catch ( Exception e) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                WaitingScreen.removePopUP();
                Status.show(Constants.CONNETION_ERROR);
            }
        });
        DebugScreen.Log("Exception inside the make connection..makePostRequest."
                + e.getMessage());
        DebugScreen.Log("Exception inside the make connection..makePostRequest."
                + e.getClass());
    }finally {
        try {
            if(inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = null;
            }
            if(out != null){
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            if(connection != null){
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    WaitingScreen.removePopUP();
                }
            });
            DebugScreen.Log("Exception from the connection2 class.."
                    + ex.getMessage());
            DebugScreen.Log("Exception from the connection2 class.."
                    + ex.getClass());
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: there should be some error in your code.

Comment: dont post it as answer. edit your question and update it.

Comment: And post the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

> Before making httpconnection from blackberry application i want to check if it is open or not.

That doesn't make sense. You want to make sure it is open before you open it. You can't. You have to try to open it, and handle the exception if it fails. That's what the exception is for.

The best way to test whether any resource is available is to try to use it. You can't predict that. You have to try it.

> Because without checking that when i tried to make a connection i got class net.rim.device.api.io.ConnectionClosedException.

So it wasn't available. So now you know. That's the correct behaviour. You're already doing the right thing. There is no question here to answer.